# Get back to first row

Tags: vba, excel

My current Columns in Excel are:

Column A: Agent's Name
Column B: Availability
Column C: Pointer

The code will basically check if Column B is Available and Column C has a pointer. If both are True then it will check the next Row if the agent is available. If not available then move to the next row. If available then move pointer to Column C of that Row.

I'm currently having problems figuring out on how to go back to the first Row of my data once the code reaches the last row. Basically the whole thing is like a loop, but I am not sure how to code it in that way. Below is my working code.

```
Sub Pointer()
    Dim lgLastRow As Long 'specify the last data row
    lgLastRow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row     
    Dim lgLastPnt As Long 
    Dim lgCurrentRow As Long 'specify the currently examined row
    Dim nxtRow As Long
    Dim nxtAvl As Long
    Dim agAly As String
    Dim status As String
    Dim pnt As String

    For lgCurrentRow = 2 To lgLastRow
        agAly = Cells(lgCurrentRow, "A")
        status = Cells(lgCurrentRow, "B")
        pnt = Cells(lgCurrentRow, "C")

        If status = "Available" And pnt = "*" Then
            Debug.Print agAly
            Cells(lgCurrentRow, "C").Select
            Selection.Cut

            nxtRow = lgCurrentRow + 1

                For nxtAvl = nxtRow To lgLastRow
                    If Cells(nxtAvl, "B") = "Available" Then
                    Cells(nxtAvl, "C").Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    nxtAvl = nxtAvl + 1
                    End If
                Next
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Going back to 1st row? Add `Range("A1").Select` (assuming row 1 is the first).

Answer (score 0):

```
        Sub Pointer()
            Dim lgLastRow As Long 'specify the last data row
            lgLastRow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
            Dim lgLastPnt As Long
            Dim lgCurrentRow As Long 'specify the currently examined row
            Dim nxtRow As Long
            Dim nxtAvl As Long
            Dim agAly As String
            Dim status As String
            Dim pnt As String

            For lgCurrentRow = 2 To lgLastRow
                agAly = Cells(lgCurrentRow, "A")
                status = Cells(lgCurrentRow, "B")
                pnt = Cells(lgCurrentRow, "C")

                If status = "Available" And pnt = "*" Then
                    Debug.Print agAly
                    Cells(lgCurrentRow, "C").Select
                    Selection.Cut

                    nxtRow = lgCurrentRow + 1

                        For nxtAvl = nxtRow To lgLastRow
                            If Cells(nxtAvl, "B") = "Available" Then
                            Cells(nxtAvl, "C").Select
                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                            nxtAvl = nxtAvl + 1
                            End If
                        Next
                End If

            Next
          Range("A1").Select
        End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not notice @PatricK comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I want the code to put the pointer in the next Agent whose status is Available. So for example, if the lastrow details are-Column B available and Colum C with pointer, I want the code to go back to the first row (let's say "A1") to see if Column B is available so that I can put the pointer in Coumn C of that row.